# PHP: Append file using $_FILES

Tags: php

I 'm writing a php to handle form uploads. Here is the code. But when uploading, php rewrites everything. I want it to check if the file name is the same, and append the content, not rewrite the file.

```
    <?php
    if ( ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain") && $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) )
     {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
         {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
         }
        else
        {
           move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        }
     }
    else
    {
          echo "Invalid file";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Hi! If the file exists then first read its content and append the newly uploaded content to them.

Comment: @C1sc0 Hi! Can you give me code or link with code? I'm new to php

Comment: $fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `move_uploaded_file` if you want to append to the file. As the name suggests, it just moves the temp file to the destination file, replacing anything that was there before.

Use `file_get_contents` to read the temp file, `file_put_contents` to write to the permanent file, and use the `FILE_APPEND` option to make it append.

```
file_put_contents($_FILES["file"]["name"], file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]), FILE_APPEND);
```

The temp file will be deleted automatically when the script ends if it's not moved by the script.